# How do you query an item from a pick list

Tags: picklist, query

Any query against a pick list causes the query to fail.

For example the Priority Column has the following options.

> Priority
>   -Critical
>   -High
>   -Medium
>   -Low

The following query results in an error

```
SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, ContactId, IsClosed, OwnerId, Status, Priority
FROM Case 
WHERE IsClosed = false AND Priority = Critical
```

There is no information that I can find in the documentation about 'pick lists' or how to add them to a query.

Update:
It looks like 'IN' might be neccesary

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index.htm

Comment: Did you try enclosing the value in single quotes? ex: Priority='Critical'

Comment: @MikeChale Thanks for the idea, I have tried single quotes.

Comment: How about using includes .Its used for multipicklist though

Answer (score 2):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm

I use 'includes' keyword  with picklists as well as multipicklists.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer:

```
SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, ContactId, IsClosed, OwnerId, Status, Priority
FROM Case 
WHERE IsClosed = false AND Priority IN ('Critical')
```

The value after in must be inside brackets and single quotes

Quote from documentation

> IN:
>   If the value equals any one of the specified values in a WHERE clause.
>   For example: SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE BillingState IN
>   ('California', 'New York') Note that the values for IN must be in
>   parentheses. String values must be surrounded by single quotes. IN and
>   NOT IN can also be used for semi-joins and anti-joins when querying on
>   ID (primary key) or reference (foreign key) fields.

Comment: You can also use Priority = 'Critical'